# Listing Post Categories on Home Page

Tags: categories

I'm trying to list categories for my posts on the home page with each of their posts under them. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

Example of what I want.

### Category 1

Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4

### Category 2

Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4

### Category 3

Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4

EDIT 2:

Got this to work.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
        echo '<h1><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </h1>';

        global $post;

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'offset'=> 0,
            'category' => $category->term_id
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            echo '
                <a href="' . $post->guid . '" title="' . $post->post_title . '">
                    ' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small') . '
                </a>
            ';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Edited post with new code

Comment: Please post working code as **answer**, so you can mark it as solution later on. That's the idea of the site :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have to run queries by category name or category ID, use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=cat_ID', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
```

Maybe [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) is more appropriate in this context (array of posts)

**EDIT:** in your edit use `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail')`instead, small is not a default size

**EDIT2:** it is better to use `the_title_attribute()` instead of `the_title()` if is in an HTML attribute :

```
title="'.the_title_attribute($post->ID).'"
```

In case you use quote in your title it will escape it so it won't break HTML

Comment: I updated the post. I need to get the thumbnails working it seems. Not sure how to get the thumbnails with `get_posts()`

Comment: I've edited code. With `get_posts()` you can get a lot, do not worry.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
        echo '<h1><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </h1>';

        global $post;

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'offset'=> 0,
            'category' => $category->term_id
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            echo '
                <a href="' . $post->guid . '" title="' . $post->post_title . '">
                    ' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'small') . '
                </a>
            ';
        }
    } 
?>
```